# Clearing control values in a page without postback from the server ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, postback

I have textboxes in a webpage where there are RequiredFieldValidators.
And at the very bottom of these controls are buttons *submit* and *clear*
Every time I click the *submit* button, it triggers the  validation from RequiredFieldValidators which is fine.
What I do not want is when I click the *clear* button the RequiredFieldValidators are also triggered.
here is my code for clear..

```
    txtFullName.Text = null;
    txtUserName.Text = null;
    txtPassword.Text = null;
    txtRetypePassword.Text = null;
    CheckList.Items.FindByText("Activated").Selected = false;
    CheckList.Items.FindByText("Suspended").Selected = false;
```

I just want to clear the controls not to validate them everytime I click the *clear* button.
Thanks :)

Comment: try setting attribute `CausesValidation="false"` and clearing `ValidationGroup` attribute of `Cancel` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You should to set property CausesValidation="false" for your clear button
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set [ValidationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validationgroup.aspx) property on controls that needs to be validated and submit button. Clear button should not have this property populated.

And according to your title, put this controls inside UpdatePanel to prevent visible postback.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use only the clear buttons' OnClientClick eventmethod and clear the various input fields by javascript only. This *should* in theory not trigger a postback, and thus also not trigger the validation.